# Insert pandas dataframes to SQL

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pymysql

I have 10,000 dataframes (which can all be transformed into JSONs). Each dataframe has 5,000 rows. So, eventually it's quite a lot of data that I would like to insert to my AWS RDS databases.
I want to insert them into my databases but I find the process using PyMySQL a bit too slow as I iterate through every single row and insert them.

First question, is there a way to insert the whole dataframe into a table straight away. I've tried using the "to_sql" function in the dataframe library but it doesn't seem to work as I am using Python 3.6

Second question, should I use NoSQL instead of RDS? What would be the best way to structure my (big) data?

Many thanks

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("mysql://......rds.amazonaws.com")
con = engine.connect()
my_df.to_sql(name='Scores', con=con, if_exists='append')
```

The table "Scores" is already existing and I would like to put all of my databases into this specific table. Or is there a better way to organise my data?

Comment: Why wouldn't `to_sql` work with Python 3.6?

Comment: ImportError: dlopen(/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're either missing the package or the package is installed in a different directory. Use a file manager to look for the missing library `libmysqlclient.21.dylib` and then copy it to the correct folder `/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so`.
My best guess is it's in either your lib or MySQLdb directory. You may also be able to find it in a virtual environment that you have set up.

Comment: I've found the libmysqlclient.21.dylib library and put it into the /Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/ folder. But it's still not working